# Unique constraint error while insert record

Tags: sql, oracle

I got an error while inserting record in to the MY_TABLE as

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.MY_TABLE_PK) violated

That might be due to the duplicate `TRANS_ID`. But I don't have any idea to sort-out this issue. How can I avoid `ORA-00001` error and insert record in to the `MY_TABLE`.

```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "MY_TABLE_PK" ON "MY_TABLE_TRANS" ("TRANS_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TEST" ;
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Insert records and then delete duplicate keys or this keys become duplicate after commit?

Comment: i need to insert record in to the MY_TABLE, in that case i got error as ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.MY_TABLE_PK) violated, i gess that error due to the MY_TABLE_PK

Comment: You can avoid this by not inserting the same value for `TRANS_ID` twice

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, could you please let me know how can debug/edit my MY_TABLE_PK

Comment: You don't need to "edit" your table. You need to change your `INSERT` statement so that they don't insert the same value twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either drop the index, if you don't care about duplicate

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE_TRANS DROP INDEX MY_TABLE_PK;
```

Or select only unique records with a group by \ distinct :

```
SELECT t.trans_id , MAX(Other Column) , MAX(...
FROM MY_TABLE_TRANS t
GROUP BY t.trans_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, is that possible to edit my MY_TABLE_PK statement without dropping

Comment: Edit it into what ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your TRANS_ID already exist into your MY_TABLE_TRANS table, you can also UPDATE the current record (if you have the rights for doing it of course)

Validate what is the record first.

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE_TRANS
WHERE trans_id = 'your trans_id here'
```

Take a look at the record. If you want to modify it, you might use an **UPDATE** instead of a new **INSERT**.

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE_TRANS
SET (put your field that need to be updated) = 'your value'
WHERE trans_id = 'your trans_id here'
```